# Want to make a function get the result of this Equation?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to make a function to get the result of (T) in this Equation

```
T = 1 /( ( 1-(f/g)^2 ) * 0.5 )
```

if f and g , are taken from the user as text box input using C#

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? That equation can almost be put into C# as-is, only dealing with possible int/float casts.

Comment: @Michael: ... and change the `^` to something else since `^` means xor in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be put into C# almost as-is. Just switch the `^` (exponent in math notation, Xor in C#) to `Math.Pow`, and that's it.

```
double f = double.Parse(this.textBoxF.Text);
double g = double.Parse(this.textBoxG.Text);

double result = 1 /( ( 1-Math.Pow(f/g, 2) ) * 0.5 )
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the asker picked one answer over the other. My best guess is I did a direct translation of their equation, without simplifying it. Darin's simplification is more efficient, but perhaps being able to verify that the code matches the given equation at a glance is important.

Answer (score 5):

Well:

```
double f = ... // take input
double g = ... // take input
double quot = f / g;
double t = 2.0 / (1 - quot * quot);
```

As far as the take input part is concerned because it is the user entering this value you will probably get a string that you will need to [parse back to a number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx):

```
double f = double.Parse(someTextBox.Text);
```

And if you wanted to handle errors gracefully you could use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) method.

Comment: @yetanothercoder, nice optimization. I will update my answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do here. Try this:

```
double f = double.Parse(text_f.Text);
double g = double.Parse(text_g.Text);

double T = 1 / ((1 - Math.Pow(f / g, 2)) * 0.5);
```